# OSSEC HIDS Installation Error (Urgent)

Tags: linux, software-installation, kali-linux

When I try to run the ./install.sh script for the OSSEC HIDS, I keep getting these weird errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: client-agent/config.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `server_ibuf'; client-agent/agentd.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: client-agent/event-forward.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `server_ibuf'; client-agent/agentd.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: client-agent/intcheck_op.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `server_ibuf'; client-agent/agentd.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: client-agent/main.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `server_ibuf'; client-agent/agentd.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: client-agent/notify.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `server_ibuf'; client-agent/agentd.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: client-agent/receiver.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `server_ibuf'; client-agent/agentd.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: client-agent/sendmsg.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `server_ibuf'; client-agent/agentd.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: client-agent/start_agent.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `server_ibuf'; client-agent/agentd.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: os_net.a(os_net.o):(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `agt'; client-agent/config.o:(.bss+0x10088): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:1017: ossec-agentd] Error 1
```

I've installed all the dependencies and updated everything (apt update, etc.) and nothing seems to fix this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Also, I'm trying to do the local installation. If you need anything else let me know

Comment: In general: these type of errors suggest that the package is broken somehow. Erase it, re-download it, perhaps a slightly older version or from another source and retry.  Otherwise try to `make clean` in every directory with a `Makefile`.  Or dig into the agent's source code.  Look specifically for `server_ibuf` and `agt`.

Comment: Could you give us more information? What OS are you using to compile the sources? What is the target (Manager/Agent)? Which is your gcc version? Another option that I would recommend if you have problems installation Ossec, is to migrate to [Wazuh](https://wazuh.com/). It is a Fork from Ossec with an active community and [professional support](https://wazuh.com/professional-services/), lot of [extra features](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/migrating-from-ossec/) and [awesome documentation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/getting-started/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

have you ever tried to install package `libsystemd-dev` ?
most of those compilation problems occur from those

to prevent this being lost in thread,

you may also try to have your build by ignoring some of the linker problems by adding `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-z,muldefs"` in front of your command such;

`LDFLAGS="-Wl,-z,muldefs" ./install.sh` or
`LDFLAGS="-Wl,-z,muldefs" make` inside src folder